# Replacing values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

If I have some sample data like the below...

```
col_1   col_2
1       <blank>
2        5
3        6
4        ?
```

how could I write a custom function that will let me replace certain values with others.  For instance, a for loop like below that would allow me to replace '?' with 0s.  Any thoughts on the below approach?

```
data_clean = function(data)
{ 
for (item in data)
{
for (i in item)
  {
  if (i == '?'){replace(i,'?',0)}
  else {do nothing}
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Try `df1$col_2[df1$col_2=='?'] <- 0`

Comment: You can also use `gsub` for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace the `?` in all the columns, either

```
 data_clean <- function(data){
   data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) replace(x, x=='?',0))
   data}
 data_clean(df1)
 #col_1   col_2
 #1     1 <blank>
 #2     2       5
 #3     3       6
 #4     4       0
```

Or

```
data_clean2 <- function(data){
      data[data=="?"] <- 0
      data}
data_clean2(df1)
#   col_1   col_2
#1     1 <blank>
#2     2       5
#3     3       6
#4     4       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(col_1 = 1:4, col_2 = c("<blank>", "5", "6", "?"
)), .Names = c("col_1", "col_2"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: My bad. I was looking at the wrong thing. Sorry @akrun!

Answer (score 1):

Following @akrun's example, another option is:

```
clean <- function(x) ifelse(x == "?", 0, x)
data.frame(apply(df1, 2, clean))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to do that. Gsub will allow you to replace values

```
df1$col_2<-gsub("\\?", 0, df1$col_2)
```

You can use sapply to do this on all columns

```
sapply(df1, function(x) gsub("\\?", 0, x))
```